# Datatables pagination characters "<<" and "<" not displaying correctly in IE and Safari

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination, datatables, html-entities

I'm using the DataTables jQuery plugin and am having issues with the First and Previous pagination links displaying correctly in IE and Safari (Firefox and Opera work).

"<<" and "<" display as "<" and "".

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     oTable = $('#fileList').dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "oLanguage": 
            {
                "sSearch": "Search all columns:",
                "oPaginate": 
                {
                    "sNext": '>',
                    "sLast": '>>',
                    "sFirst": '<<',
                    "sPrevious": '<'
                }
            }
});
```

I have attempted to escape '\<\<' to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [character entity references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_entity_reference) `&lt;` and `&gt;` for `<` and `>`respectively.

You might also want to know about `&amp;` too which is used to display `&`.

Comment: Of course!  I think what threw me was that it only broke on the previous buttons and only on 50% of the browsers I tested.

Answer (score 4):

These are the correct character entities to use in your case.

For < and > use `&lt;` and `&gt;`

For << and >> use `&laquo;` and `&raquo;`